# D3 - Add a raw symbol

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a `D3` code.

I want to add a svg symbol "as is"! to the `D3` svg.

I dont want to create the symbol dynamically using D3, I have the symbols already made from our designer and i want to use it as is!

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omriman12/8786e8zq/1/

In the fiddle I have my d3 container `pie_chart_wrapper` and i want to add the symbol `md_file` to the d3 svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add previous definded symbol to your SVG:

```
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform","translate(0,0)")
   .attr("class","mySymbol")
   .append("use")
   .attr("xlink:href","#md_file")
```

[Here the working code](https://jsfiddle.net/7ugfvy0j/)

After append `use` your can tweak their attributes, like so:

```
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform","translate(0,0)")
   .attr("class","mySymbol")
   .append("use")
   .attr("width",20)
   .attr("heigth", 20)
   .style("fill", "red")
       .
       .
       .
   .attr("xlink:href","#md_file")
```