# D3.js - Appending LinearIcons to SVG

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I'm struggling with how to append icons from this website - https://linearicons.com/  to an svg using d3.js.

Currently, my best effort is to download the svg itself although I haven't worked out how to dictate the size and colour - CSS?

```
my_svg.append("image")
      .attr("class",'apart')
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("xlink:href","apartment.svg");
```

These lines have no effect:

```
     .attr("fill","red")
     .attr("width", 40)
     .attr("height", 40)
```

Ideally I want to replicate inline SVG with  but can't work it out:

```
<svg class="lnr lnr-user"><use xlink:href="#lnr-user"></use></svg>
```

I could also embed the symbol tag but again I can't work out how to reference it properly.  There is a working example here which doesn't apply to me as I need to create the svg etc... dynamically:

[D3 - Add a raw symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170380/d3-add-a-raw-symbol)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Font Version**

I wouldn't use the `svg` version of the font, instead use the [font itself](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css%22%3E).  Then, the key is to look in that `CSS` file and get the Unicode character of the icon you want, for example `home`:

```
.lnr-home:before {
    content: "\e800";
}
```

is Unicode character:

```
\ue800
```

You can then use a standard `text` element.  In `d3` syntax:

```
.append('text')
.attr('font-family', 'Linearicons-Free')
.attr('font-size', '2em' )
.text('\ue800')
```

---

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500);
      
    svg.selectAll('text')
      .data(["\ue810", "\ue80e", "\ue854", "\ue884"])
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('font-family', 'Linearicons-Free')
      .attr('font-size', '2em' )
      .text(function(d) { return d })
      .attr('transform', function(d,i){ return 'translate(' + [(i * 50) + 50, (i * 50) +  50] + ')'; });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**SVG Version**

If you have your heart set on using the `svg` versions, I can make it work but it's a little kludgey.  First, you need to have an existing `<use>` on your page for the `svgembedder`, then you can append `use` elements:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/svgembedder.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- this needs to be here for svgemedder to work -->
  <svg width="0" height="0"><use xlink:href="#dummy"></use></svg>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500);
      
    svg.selectAll('.icon')
      .data(["user", "home", "thumbs-up", "cross"])
      .enter()
      .append('use')
      .attr('width',50)
      .attr('height',50)
      .attr('transform', function(d,i){ return 'translate(' + [(i * 50) + 50, (i * 50) +  50] + ')'; })
      .attr('xlink:href', function(d) { return '#lnr-' + d });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your comments Mark.  I worked out the clunky approach - see below - but will transfer to your text approach.  As you say it's more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

I've cracked it:

```
my_svg.append('use')
    .attr("xlink:href","#lnr-user")
    .attr("x", width-icon_pos)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("fill","red”);
```

Which works a treat as long as the index file has the following script reference:

```
<script src="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/svgembedder.min.js"></script>
```